# Female terminal pin

Tags: terminal

What is this female terminal pin called, Everywhere I look I can only find slightly similar ones, but no matches, Even a reverse Google Image search pulls up some weird alternatives

[image]
[image]

[image]

The only ones I can find are these

[image]
[image]

I need this specific type because the lip at the end of the female terminal locks into a peg-pergeo battery connector... Peg-perego is a battery connector for a kid's "plastic" 4 wheeler. I don't have the slightest clue where to start looking for connectors besides Amazon and ebay, so any Information would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

This is the other end of that connector

[image]

Comment: You will need to find the connector it came from. There are thousands of connector types and large fraction of them have unique crimp terminals like this. They all look very similar so I don't think we could possibly identify it unless its an extremely common one.

Comment: What is a "peg-pergeo battery connector"? Why not search for that?

Comment: Seems to be a typo error for an Italian distributor of  just about anything related to baby products and not electronic components

Comment: BTW,  you're crimping your new wire wrong.  The part you have crimped on the bare wire is meant to crimp around the insulation (for strain relief).  The wire crimp is the next set of tabs down.

Comment: @kyle B that was done by the manufacturer, I just pulled the terminals from their housing. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: @hellomoto   They did it wrong then.  That's why the wire broke off.  If they crimped it right, wouldn't have broken off at that point.

Comment: Does that piece plug into the battery directly?   Or is there a mating adaptor on another wire???      No offense, but if you'd bought a real Fisher Price "Power Wheels", not a Chinese knock off, you wouldn't be having this problem and you'd be able to get replacement pieces easily.

Comment: @Kyle B is there a site somewhere where I can search for just female crimp connectors, Instead of looking at the generic assortments sold at the popular retail stores.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, Thanks. there's a second mating adapter that the plug snaps Into.

Comment: Chances are very high you will "never" find an identical connector.   Is there any logo or anything that identifies the manufacturer of that piece?   There are literally "millions" of those connectors out there, and this one is whatever that company could find that was cheapest.   The popular retail stores will carry only stuff from relatively well known and established manufacturers - What you have in your hand comes from some second-tier manufacturer.   I don't know everything EE in the world, but when it comes to "toy manufacturing in China", I'm what you might call an "expert"...

Comment: You have two options here. Either try to find the connector _housing_ first and then compatible pins (they usually listed in the housing datasheet), or cut both sides off and replace them with any suitable wire-to-wire connectors. Any of the usual parts suppliers (digikey, mouser, farnell etc.) will have plenty of choices

Comment: If you can cut the connectors off, your best bet then is to replace with something more standard and available.   PM me, for real.  I can't say anything else here.....

Comment: @hellomoto There are several such sites, such as digi-key, mouser, newark, and probably plenty of others I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "TAPP12V Connector" and if you google it you will see literally hundreds of sources for them. Here are some examples: [one](https://www.amazon.ca/Blue-Perego-Battery-Side-Connector/dp/B071WT1JX8), [two](https://www.batterychargers.com/en/products/accessories/tapp12v12v-battery-cable-connector-charging-peg-perego%C2%AE-ride-toys), [three](https://www.amazon.ca/Schumacher-TAPP12V-Connector-PEREGO-Charge/dp/B06XT6DY3L).

They mostly come pre-wired with slightly more common connector on the other side. You can either use that connector or cut it off and splice the wires.

Main point is - do not waste time looking for pins, buy "Peg Perego battery harness" and use it to replace the connector.

Another option (which I don't like) is to crimp the wire where it is supposed to go - into second pair of tabs. Since you would not be able to crimp insulation too chances are it will break off again eventually.

Comment: your example one looks like quite a ripoff, considering the price on example two....

Comment: @Hearth luckily there are hundreds more to choose from. I simply listed first three that popped up in a search.